Question about a specific PDE with singularity
I have the following system of PDEs for a metric $h_{AB}$ and a function $f$,
$f D_t^{(2)}h_{AB} + \left(D_tf + \dfrac{1}{2}h^{AB}D_t h_{AB}\right)D_t h_{AB} -\dfrac{1}{2}f h^{CD}D_t h_{AC} D_t h_{BD} + R_{AB}^h = \lambda h_{AB},$
$D_t^{(2)}f + \dfrac{1}{2}h^{AB}D_t h_{AB} D_t f = 2\lambda$
$2D_t \left(h^{AB}D_th_{AB}\right) + h^{AB}h^{CD}D_t h_{AC} D_t h_{BD}=0,$
where $R^h$ is the Ricci tensor of $h$ and $\lambda$ is a real constant. The initial conditions are
$h(t=0) = h_0,\qquad D_th(t=0)=K, \qquad f(t=0)=0, \qquad \text{and}\qquad D_tf(t=0)=2\kappa,$
where $h_0$ is a metric, $K$ is a symmetric, 2-covariant tensor field, and $\kappa$ is a constant.
I would like to know if the system admits a solution and if it is unique. Since the function $f$ vanishes at $t=0$ one cannot use the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem. I have read about Fuchsian ODEs that present a symilar behaviour (when $\kappa\neq 0$), but I don't know if it applies to PDEs as in my case. I also know an extension of the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem by Fusaro, but it does not apply in this case neither. Does anyone know any result that may apply in this situation? Or any idea about what to do or to search? Thanks!
